# Mac ImportError: No module named stackauth

Tags: python

I want to import stackauth but I'm not sure how to install it

```
>>> import stackauth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named stackauth
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use easy_install, as specified by the [instructions](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python)

```
easy_install py-stackexchange
```